# how to fix ModuleNotFoundError: no module named bs4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a program that takes a set of numbers from a webpage and adds them up together. I used the beautifulsoup module that I installed(ran "pip install beautifulsoup4 in command prompt).

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
web=request.urlopen('http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_845350.html').read()
x = BeautifulSoup(html)
tags=x('span')
sum=0
for tag in tags:
    sum = sum+int(tag.contents[0])
print(sum)
```

However, whenever I run the program, python gives me a ModuleNotFoundError: no module named bs4. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you look [here](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/), you see that
`pip install beautifulsoup4` should do the job.

If you are on Linux you might have to use `pip3` instead.

Comment: I installed it with "pip install beautifulsoup4", and i've tried uninstalling then re-installing it. Nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Are you in a virtual environment?

Comment: I would always use `python -m pip install beautifulsoup4` but that might just be me.

Comment: `pip install bs4`

Comment: I am not in a virtual enviroment, and I tried pip install bs4 and it didnt work for me either

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than one version of Python installed on your machine?

If so, try running

```
pip --version
```

Will return something like this

```
pip 18.1 from c:\...\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.6)
```

Then verify if you are using the same version to run your script

Comment: They are on the same version